# how to turn off multithreading gdb execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb, cygwin

I really like to use some simple interface like in Borland C++, thereby I've installed cygwin with gcc/gdb/vim etc on my laptop(unfortunately, I can not install Linux here :( )

The problem that I have is following: when I try to debug non-parallized program, f.e:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i = argc;
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello World %d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

my gdb hangs:

```
$ gdb a.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.50.20111026-cvs (cygwin-special)
...
Reading symbols from /cygdrive/c/programming/temp/a.exe...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401179: file helloworld.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /cygdrive/c/programming/temp/a.exe
**[New Thread 12132.0x11a4]
[New Thread 12132.0x32ac]**

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x28ac60) at helloworld.cpp:4
4       int main(int argc, char **argv) {
(gdb) n
5         int i = argc;
(gdb)
6           fprintf(stdout, "Hello World %d\n", i);
(gdb) p i
$1 = 1
(gdb) n
.......... nothing here
```

I cannot terminate this debugging by C-C, C-Z or killing.
I think gdb hangs, because it tries to use 2 threads and something goes wrong. Here is info threads:

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  2    Thread 10160.0x31e8 0x775cf8e5 in ntdll!RtlUpdateClonedSRWLock () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll
* 1    Thread 10160.0x15a8 main (argc=1, argv=0x28ac60) at helloworld.cpp:4
```

For me, that's pretty strange, that 1-thread program is executed on 2 threads. I've checked gdb on Linux and gdb there uses 1 thread.

My question is: can I say to gdb to use only 1 thread anyhow?

BTW, I didn't have same problem before until I've updated my laptop and cygwin. I tried to rollback gdb(7.3.50 actually is the oldest one that cygwin suggests), but it doesn't help.

Thank you

Comment: That is indeed a simple program which should not require threads, but who knows what cygwin is doing "behind the scenes". I doubt that gdb crashes/hangs because of the threads, it must be something else. Have you search google for problems with that setup and those versions? Also, can you execute the program successfully without using GDB?

Comment: thank you for reply. Yes, I tried to find an answer in google, but all "hangs" topics were too old (<2006 year) and those answers don't help me.
Yes, I can execute program, moreover, I can execute it under gdb without breakpoints...

Comment: I've noticed, that gdb writes me something right before I close window with it:

    [New Thread 7600.0x3390]
    [Inferior 1 (process 7600) exited with code 030000000472]

Comment: Try adding an fflush(stdout); to flush the output after the fprintf() although it really shouldn't be hanging after having called fprintf().

The other suggestion I have is trying MinGW rather than the cygwin provided versions as I've come across weird bugs with them before.